# How to set up Icinga2 master (for remote clients) without using CLI wizard?

Tags: icinga2

As a follow up question to [How to set up Icinga2 remote client without using CLI wizard?](https://serverfault.com/questions/647805/how-to-set-up-icinga2-remote-client-without-using-cli-wizard), I want to setup the master in an automated way.

Answer (score 1):

Example script to solve the question above. Enjoy!

```
HOSTNAME=`cat /etc/hostname`
icinga2 pki new-ca
chown nagios:nagios /etc/icinga2/pki
icinga2 pki new-cert --cn ${HOSTNAME} --key /etc/icinga2/pki/${HOSTNAME}.key --csr /etc/icinga2/pki/${HOSTNAME}.csr --cert /etc/icinga2/pki/${HOSTNAME}.crt
icinga2 pki sign-csr --csr /etc/icinga2/pki/${HOSTNAME}.csr --cert /etc/icinga2/pki/${HOSTNAME}.crt # typo fixed :)
cp -vR --preserve=all /var/lib/icinga2/ca/ca.crt /etc/icinga2/pki
cat >/etc/icinga2/zones.conf << EOFZONECONF
/**
 * Generated by $0.
 */

object Endpoint "${HOSTNAME}" {
}

object Zone "master" {
        //this is the local node master named  = "master"
        endpoints = [ "${HOSTNAME}" ]
}
EOFZONECONF
icinga2 feature enable api
# The next three lines modify the NodeName and TicketSalt assignments
sed -i "s/\/\/const NodeName.*/const NodeName = \"${HOSTNAME}\"/" /etc/icinga2/constants.conf
SALT=`cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z0-9' | fold -w 16 | head -n 1`
sed -i "s/const TicketSalt.*/const TicketSalt = \"${SALT}\"/" /etc/icinga2/constants.conf
service icinga2 restart
```

Comment: Could you explain what this means?

Comment: Are you familiar with icinga?

Comment: You are not generating the csr you are signing later.

Comment: Nice catch!  I missed a line when copy pasting / editing for this entry, now added at line 4 above.