# Using Ansible to add Icinga2 agent to master node

Tags: icinga2

I want to use Ansible to add Icinga2 passive monitoring for my hosts with agent monitoring.  I have a single master node and am not using satellites yet.

I've had some success in setting up the client side thanks to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/647805/how-to-set-up-icinga2-remote-client-without-using-cli-wizard) and [this old post](https://monitoring-portal.org/woltlab/index.php?thread/35989-using-ansible-to-generate-the-icinga-client-certificates/) on an archived forum.

What commands do I need to run on the master node to add in the remote node?

I'm using Ansible so I specifically want to avoid the wizard they provide.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite detailed documentation at https://icinga.com/docs/icinga2/snapshot/doc/06-distributed-monitoring/#top-down-config-sync